# iOS8 - How to manage user session in sharing extension

Tags: ios8

iOS8 introduce sharing extension to share photos to my app from other app. But we must check login session when user click post. How to manage the user session?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Access token stored in UserDefaults of App to check weather the User is logged in or Not and if Not then in that case you can use Custom UI to show something and Disable the Post Button.

And Also can put same validation at

```
didSelectPost
```

before posting it ahead.